# How to perform regression in loop using multiple columns from different CSV files

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have the same number of columns and rows stored in two csv files. Now I want to compute correlation R and R-squared between the same columns from two CSVs (c1 vs c1, c2 vs c2, ...). Here is my code but it is unable to perform the task:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from scipy import stats
import statsmodels.api as sm
import math

df1 = np.loadtxt('data1_1981_2007_DD.csv', delimiter=',') 
df2 = np.loadtxt('data2_1981_2007_DD.csv', delimiter=',') 

correlation_r2 = r2_score(df1, df2)
```

The shape of df1 and df2 are (9861, 10).

After running the code I am getting only a single value. I want to get all 10 values for r2. Can somebody help with this?

Comment: columns are 10, rows are 9861

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are computing the correlation of two vectors. To compute the correlation of each pair of values in these two columns, you need to use logic like this:

```
correlation_r2 = [r2_score(df1[i], df2[i]) for i in range(len(df1))]
```

Comment: I think the shapes are off.  For `(9861, 10)` you'll need `correlation_r2 = [r2_score(df1[:, i], df2[:, i]) for i in range(df1.shape[1])]`

Comment: I have only 10 columns but r2 is coming as per no. of rows (9861). It should be 10.